# How to add exchange course to currency in dataframe

Tags: r

I need to add a new column with exchange rates. Is it possible with the mutate function?

Example:

```
> dat 
  currency
1 $
2 €
3 £
4 ¥
```

output:

```
> dat 
  currency  ex_rate
1 $         1
2 €         0.8
3 £         0.55
4 ¥         130
```

Thank you!

Comment: You may have key/value dataset and join

Comment: It's a big dataset with 1000+ rows and I have to add the $ exchange course to the already existing currency column.

Comment: that is why i menioned to create key.value dataset i.e. `keydat <- data.frame(currency = c("$", "€", "£", "¥"), ex_rate = c(1, 0.8, 0.55, 130)); left_join(dat, key_dat)`